# X-CSRF-Token issue in ionic. Every time a different token is received

Tags: authentication, drupal, ionic-framework, token, drupal-services

I have a backend with Drupal.

Using **Drupal Services** to interact with. Which provides a rest server.
Created endpoint named **'api'**.

Following sequence works **in normal browser or any http client like postman** :-

- example.com/api/login (works).
- api sends back user data  (token,session id, session name etc).
- Further any request I make, I send token as X-CSRF-Token (all requests work).
- I can even logout the same session with the token received before.

**IN IONIC APP :-**

I can login and I also store user data (token, session data etc.) in local storage after login.

**Here's the difference in app :-**

When I send the same token back to server while making a request (say logout).

Server's response is **"User is not Logged In."**

Why does this happen?

**Update :-**

After logging in I tried getting the current token from the server, and it was different from the one I saved after successfully logging in.

Every time a different token is received.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Problem was i never set the cookie and chrome did this for me automatically.

Luckily i found this great site:

[drupalionic.org](http://drupalionic.org)

There are links to a view demos as well as good descriptions and code.

So what you have to do is:
- log in 
- retrieve session data and set cookie 
- perform subsequent requests with the cookie data and X-CSRF-Token in your header

Here is a flowchart:

[image]

Was this helpful for you?

Comment: yes its surely helpful ! atleast now i know that cookies are required.

Before i tried forming cookie and sending it everytime but it didnt work !


The image shows two headers as 'X-csrf-token' & 'Authoriztion'.

is it Authorization or Cookie header ?

any shrt example what to pass in Authorization ?